# TypeError: e.values is undefined in nvd3 graph

Tags: json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have plotted a nvd3 graph by taking real-time data from an external JSON file(temp.json). This is my code. but I'm getting "**TypeError: e.values is undefined**" error.

```
d3.json("temp.json", function(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = +d.timestamp;
        d.timestamp3 = +d.timestamp3;

    });
nv.addGraph(function(){
var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                .margin({left: 100})
                .x(function(d){return d.timestamp})
                .y(function(d){return d.timestamp3})
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)


chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Time in ns')
    .tickFormat(d3.format(""));

    chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Timestamp in ns')
        .tickFormat(d3.format(""));

    d3.select('#container svg')
        .datum(data)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);



    return chart;
});
});
```

My data in temp.json:

```
[{
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718629809",
        "timestamp2": "1370718629900",
        "timestamp3": "1370718629945"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718630000",
        "timestamp2": "1370718631000",
        "timestamp3": "1370718631500"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718632000",
        "timestamp2": "1370718632500",
        "timestamp3": "1370718632600"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718633000",
        "timestamp2": "1370718633500",
        "timestamp3": "1370718634000"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718635000",
        "timestamp2": "1370718635500",
        "timestamp3": "1370718636000"
    }
]
```

what is the error? and How to get plot of timestamp vs timestamp3? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVD3 expects data to be in this format:

```
[
  {
     key: 'my dataset',
     values: [...]
  }
]
```

You could do:

```
const processedData = [{
   key: 'my dataset',
   values: data
}];

d3.select('#container svg')
    .datum(processedData)
    .call(chart);
```

Comment: can't I use current JSON file(temp.json)? Isn't it is a valid JSON format to graph nvd3?

Comment: So I should use like this: [
  {
    "key": "timestamp",
    "values": [ 1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809,1370718629809 ] 
}, 
]

Comment: You can just use the code I provided in the answer:
const processedData = [{
   key: 'my dataset',
   values: data
}];

d3.select('#container svg')
    .datum(processedData)
    .call(chart);

Comment: Thanks it is working. If I want to generate three lines in a single graph(ie., timestamp,timestamp2,timestamp3) how should I take the values?

Comment: Add three different series.
const data = [{ key: 'series1', values: [..]}, { key: 'series2', values: [..]}, { key: 'series3', values: [..]}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142795/discussion-between-darshan-theerth-and-jeznag).